# How to get all data from web sockets?

Tags: javascript, websocket

there is the site, using wss, as we can see, browser shows all data from send/recieve

but js socket.addEventListener("message".... proccesess only my own requests to server
how to get all data like browser does?

[browser network ws](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LCeqf.png)

Comment: What do you mean with: "How to get all data from web sockets?" The message event is fired when the server  send a message to you: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebSocket/onmessage

Comment: browser shows all messages

socket.addEventListener("message", event => {

        console.log(event.data);
 
})
shows only answers to my requests
see picture

Comment: Thats exactly what i have writen. The "onMessage" event listener only shows message from your server send to your client.

Comment: Its possible that the "empty" messages, are ping/pong requests/answers. They are used to check if the websocket connections is still active: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebSockets_API/Writing_WebSocket_servers#pings_and_pongs_the_heartbeat_of_websockets

Comment: so, is it possible to get (inspect) all traffic data, using js or something else?

Comment: i assume that are ping/pong events. There is no need to inspect these kind of events/messages. You can read more about theme on the mdn in my links. These a binary messages. Possible xy problem: https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378 What are you trying to archiv?

Comment: i want to get data of the certain message, that contains id of the coins drop in that casino. Server really sends such message. That is why i need to get all data to find that message

Comment: If the server send the message, than the "message" event is to 99.999% fired. I really suggest you to read & understand more about websockets from the links i gave you. The empty messages shown in your console are not relvant for you debugging. Create a WebSocket client in node.js connect to your ws endpoint and work with the "utils" package and chromium debug tool (use --inspect) and you clearly see that the "empty" message is a binary ping/pong event. You need to understand how websocket "message" is build.

Comment: )  the chat on the site uses ws, so that messages also contains readable information in plain text, as and messages with data of drops. i dont care about empty messages. let them be. thx